# Collect (almost) all light from a point source

Tags: optics, experimental-physics

If I have a point source of light which I can surround with a curved mirror/lens. Is there a well known technique to try to collect all the light from the point source and direct it onto a photodetector? I am imagining something like an internally mirrored cone with an internally mirrored spherical base surrounding the source and a photodetector at the point of the cone.

Obviously no system like this is perfect, the light source would have structure to hold it in place, etc

I feel like I can't be the first person to want to do this, but I'm not sure what to google to find resources on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The classical solution is an ellipsoidal mirror. In the same way that a parabolic reflector focuses parallel rays coming in from infinity onto a single focus, an elliptical reflector will reflect all of the rays that originate from one focal point onto the other one. Thus, if you're OK with having the light hit your photodetector from all directions (and you're OK with both source and detector floating in space, or with the loss of effectiveness caused by supporting rods) then this solution would work.

In practice, of course, it depends on what you're doing, what the practical constraints are, and what variations you're willing to accept.

Comment: There is for example the [4πPAC group](https://mpl.mpg.de/research-at-mpl/leuchs-emeritus-group/research/4pipac-group/) doing this.